# Time complexity of this function that calculates 2^n

Tags: c++, time, time-complexity

i was trying to find the time complexity of this function but i couldn't
this function calculates `2^n` with `n` given, I'm not sure if its `O(log n)` or `O(n)`.

```
unsigned long pot2_1(unsigned n)
{
    if (n==0) return 1;
    if (n%2==0) return pot2_1( n/2 ) * pot2_1( n/2 );
    else return 2 * pot2_1( n/2 ) * pot2_1( n/2 );
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `pot2_1` recursively twice instead of calling it once and storing the result in a variable (to achieve O(log(n))?

Comment: yeah I know I just wanted to try like this because It was really confusing for me to find the time complexity with this code

Answer (score 3):

Its O(n)
The recursion always go to pot2_1(1) n times before calculate.

In other words its calculate pot2_1(n/2) two times